# How to access module-level names in Python?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
import m

def f(m=None):
    if m is None:
        k = m.M() # I want this m to refer to the imported module, not the parameter
```

I would really prefer to keep both the parameter name and the module name the same. Is there a way explicitly to refer to the module m?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind changing the module's name only within the importing module, you could do:

```
import m as m_

def f(m=None):
    if m is None:
        k = m_.M()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the parameter the same as the *usual* module name, for code readability, but can tolerate the module being temporarily renamed for this scope, you can do something like this:

```
import m as _m

def f(m=None):
    if m is None:
        k = _m.M()
```

Not ideal, but probably the closest you can get.

Answer (score 1):

a module in python is just another object, so the `globals()`-builtin will work fine:

```
import m

def f(m=None):
    if m is None:
        k = globals()['m'].M()
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's just within this one function where the name clash occurs, you can always re-import the module within the function's scope and rename it to avoid the ambiguity.

```
import m

def f(m=None):
    import m as the_real_m
    if m is None:
        k = the_real_m.M()
```

The `m` in `import m as the_real_m` can be a little confusing, but here it's *not* a variable reference so there's no problem with it resolving to the wrong thing.

Personally I'd rather rename the function argument, but I realise with keyword arguments the name of the argument can be part of the interface exposed to other parts of the system, and keeping that with the clearest name possible can be more important.

Answer (score -2):

You can set the default value of the parameter m to be the attribute of the module, like this:

```
import m

def f(m=m.M):
    m()
```

However, shadowing a global (the module name) with a parameter is not the most Pythonic way to do it. More Pythonically, you'd name the parameter M, which matches the method M that it's going to be acting as.

```
import m

def f(M=m.M):
    M()
```

This way, you can still refer to other attributes of the module if you need to.

Comment: and what if you want to pass something else to the function? that's not a good solution.

Comment: then you pass it, and it overrides the DEFAULT value in the function definition.

Comment: no. binding a module to a parameter as default value just to be able to use it in the function is just not something you do. try to explain that parameter to somebody using your module. the only reason to do that would be if you would like to be able to pass in a differen object to change what the function is doing.

Comment: We're not binding a module as a parameter, we're binding an attribute of a module, and as it is, the only reason you'd pass a different value there would be to change what it's doing.

Comment: Isn't m.M mutable and therefore shouldn't be used as a default parameter value?